# Connect to a secure web socket from a specific website

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I want to automate actions on momio.me programmatically using python.

To do so I need to connect to wss://de.momio.me/pipe and then send the messages accordingly

I have tried connecting to the websocket directly but as soon as I sent a message it immediately closed the connection.

I could use selenium as an alternative to achieve the automation but I would not be able to learn much this way.

I'd be thankful for any leads or tutorials on how this is usually achieved.

I assume the last thing I am missing is the Sec-Token that is being passed in the web sockte's initial request, however I have inspected the network traffic and was unable to find it which is unusual since it changes on every connect.

Comment: Please update your question to add more details about the problem. Were there any error messages? What did you do to connect?

Comment: I assume the last thing I am missing is the Sec-Token that is being passed in the web sockte's initial request, however I have inspected the network traffic and was unable to find it which is unusual since it changes on every connect